# Refused to execute script from packs/js/index-662807e73049021453fe.js' because its MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: mime-types, ruby-on-rails-6, script-tag

Im deploying a website with aws ec2 instance using react/rails.
When running the server through rails s -e production
i get this error

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://<ip-address>/packs/js/index-662807e73049021453fe.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

my application.erb.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Production server</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ive been looking for an answer for a week now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

my routes to catch all routes in routes.rb

```
 root 'homepage#index'
  get ':path', to: 'homepage#index', format: false
```

and that points to homepage view

```
 <%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>
 <%= react_component("App", {prerender: true}) %>
```

Comment: i replaced the server ip address with localhost for this question @Bergi

Comment: The problem is not with the html page that contains the `<script>` tag. The problem is with the `/packs/js` route of the web server which delivers html instead of javascript (at least according to its mime type).

Comment: I updated my question to include all 3 js files in the packs/ folder. Thank you!

Comment: It's not the contents of the js files. It's the server (probably some ruby?) that is serving them with the wrong http headers.

Comment: Im lost sorry if im not catching on, but where in ruby could i tell it to load js, i included the routes and view that should be loading the js files

Comment: It's not the loading of the script - you're telling the browser to load the right script, that all seems to work just fine. It's when the browser fetches the script resource from the server that the server responds wrong. I have no ruby experience though so I don't know where to look for that either.

Comment: My issue was related to I was trying my javascript in a non-root route. Hope it helps :)